# How do I dynamically append a <span> tag into a specific location of the <p> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

In essence, I'm trying to implement a feature which highlights certain text when selected. This is strictly for the Google Chrome browser.

For example:
Before selection:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>sample text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

After selecting "text" from "sample text":

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>sample <span class="state-highlighted">text</span> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {

    // Assume we have checked that mousedown position is different from mouseup position.
    // Not sure what to do after this.

  });
});
```

I could start with a simpler question:
How do I insert a span element into a paragragh element, let's say on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`Range.surroundContents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents) method that would come handy here, but it will throw when selecting only part of an element.
So in your case it might be better to [extract the content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/extractContents) of the current Range, append it in your new node, and then [insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range/insertNode) that new node where the Range is:

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  const sel = getSelection();
  const range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  const highlighter = document.createElement('span');
  highlighter.classList.add('highlight');
  highlighter.append(range.extractContents());
  range.insertNode(highlighter);
})
```

```css
.highlight { color: red; }
```

```html
<p id="target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

On mouseup, call `window.getSelection()` to get a [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object. You can examine it to find the start and end text of the selection inside the `<p>`. Then replace the `<p>`'s HTML to surround that section of text with `<span class="highlighted">`:

```js
const p = document.body.querySelector('p');
const origContent = p.textContent;
p.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  p.textContent = origContent;
});
p.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection) {
    return;
  }
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  // If user starts highlighting on the right, and drags mouse to the left,
  // endOffset will be smaller than startOffset:
  const startIndex = Math.min(range.startOffset, range.endOffset);
  const { length } = String(selection);
  const endIndex = startIndex + length;
  p.textContent = p.textContent;
  p.innerHTML = (
    p.textContent.slice(0, startIndex) +
    '<span class="highlighted">' +
    selection +
    '</span>' +
    p.textContent.slice(endIndex)
  );
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p>sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</p>
```

If the user might select more than one part of the text at a time, and you'd want to highlight both discontiguous pieces of text, you can iterate over the ranges from 0 to `selection.rangeCount` and slice the original context to create the new HTML accordingly.