# How to make bold text in content editable div with raw text processing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make font bold text with text processing instead of using `execute.commands`. Because I want make another functionality that not in `execute.command`.

**Here is the code:**

```js
var selectedRange;
var selectedText = '';
let editor = document.getElementById('editor')


String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};


function actionBold(e){


     let input = e.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]

    if(input != null){
        input.checked = !input.checked
    }

 
    if(selectedText.length != 0){

        let edited = editor.innerHTML.replaceBetween(selectedRange.start, selectedRange.end, `<b>${selectedText}</b>`)
        editor.innerHTML = edited
    }
}

function getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(element) {
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    var doc = element.ownerDocument || element.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    var sel;
    if (typeof win.getSelection != "undefined") {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
            start = preCaretRange.toString().length;
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            end = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        }
    } else if ( (sel = doc.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var textRange = sel.createRange();
        var preCaretTextRange = doc.body.createTextRange();
        preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", textRange);
        start = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
        end = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
    }
    return { start: start, end: end };
}

function onMouseUp() {
 
    const sel = window.getSelection();
    var arr  = []
    for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
        arr.push(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents().textContent);
    }
    selectedText = arr.join();

     selectedRange = getSelectionCharacterOffsetWithin(editor)
}
```

```css
input{

    display: none;
}

input:checked+svg{

    background-color: rgb(194, 10, 10);
    fill: #fff;
}

label{

    cursor: pointer;
}


#editor{

    width: 50%;
    min-height: 40px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <label  onclick="actionBold(this); return false">
        <input class="none" type="checkbox" name="0" checked>
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24"><path d="M15.6 10.79c.97-.67 1.65-1.77 1.65-2.79 0-2.26-1.75-4-4-4H7v14h7.04c2.09 0 3.71-1.7 3.71-3.79 0-1.52-.86-2.82-2.15-3.42zM10 6.5h3c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5s-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5h-3v-3zm3.5 9H10v-3h3.5c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5s-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
     </label>

    <div onmouseup="onMouseUp()" id="editor" contenteditable>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim omnis ea, voluptas maxime perspiciatis praesentium magni repellendus earum suscipit sint. Veritatis fuga adipisci accusantium similique distinctio vero tenetur ipsam fugiat.</p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am able to get selected range and I replaced the selected string with `<b>` tag to get bold font. But the problem is with HTML tags are not counted in range either I don't know how to proceed this further.

I am fine with open source libraries and premium libraries but I want to study it how it works. That's why I trying it my own.

Currently I am using raw text processing. Can anyone knows How to proceed this logically to get successful text editor for bold font only? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you basically trying to do the same as in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606037/

Comment: @Kaiido, Yes It's what I wanted in this question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following method from [Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range)

`extractContents`: to extract the selected content, so we can wrap it with bold tag.

`insertNode`: putting back the modified content in the same position.

```
let editor = document.getElementById('editor');
var preCaretRange;

function actionBold(e){
    var bold = document.createElement('b'); // created bold tag
    bold.appendChild(preCaretRange.extractContents()); // extracting and wrapping the content with tag
    preCaretRange.insertNode(bold); // insert the modified content back

}

function onMouseUp() {
    var doc = editor.ownerDocument || editor.document;
    var win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow;
    preCaretRange = win.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Is there any idea to get the tags for that selected element. Because the issue is the bold font is working nice. But If I click again, It'll add another bold tag.

Comment: Please see this image: https://ibb.co/mXHbFmm | The purpose bold is using for one time. So, If any method to detect selected text tags even with raw text processing, It's really helpful.

Comment: If you know please tell how can I detect tags. In **TEXT** If I place cursor in **X** i need to get the tag tree like `X => <div><p class="some"><b>`. So, I can know **X** is bold or not.  I don't know whether it's complex or simple. Do you know any Idea about this? Am I need to study any algorithm for this kinda programming?

Comment: There is a way to find the _parent tag_ with `win.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.tagName` and for _child tags_ is `win.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.getElementsByTagName("*")`, for reptitive bold tags we need to write explicit logic to clean it up.